# 2020 Moderator Election - interest check

Tags: discussion, moderation, election

This community hasn't had any new moderators since 2017 and has never had an election. Over the past few months, this site has lost members of its moderator team and we need to make sure that this site has moderators to meet your needs. Fortunately, this site is pretty quiet and moderator work isn't burdensome.

In general we want to keep a team of at least three moderators on any site. This makes sure that there's coverage in the case of people being on vacation or dealing with life while also giving them people to discuss issues with. We'd like an election to be successful so I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election. Like I mentioned, we're looking at scheduling the nomination period to start some time in June '20.

NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination.