# Announcing a Pro Tempore Moderator election - Nominations begin August 17th

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Computer Graphics Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **August 17th** to bring in two more moderators.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on August 17th, users can [nominate themselves](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On August 24th, if there are three or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidate/s. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, we'll announce the results on meta on September 1st.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Answer (score 4):

We have just extended this nomination process for another week, due to not having enough candidates nominate themselves, this means that all dates are moved forward one week.

- On August 31st, if there are three or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidate/s. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, we'll announce the results on meta on September 8th.

Answer (score 2):

> users can nominate themselves

Considering the responses to your previous [interest check for moderator election](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298/2020-moderator-election-interest-check), I am not sure if there will be any candidates nominating themselves.

However, I think we do need some new moderators here and maybe some candidates stay away from nominating themselves for some minor reasons like thinking there are better candidates or not being sure if they would be good moderators. So maybe we can use the [procedure from the previous election](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130/who-should-our-moderators-be) by also letting the community suggest candidates.

Alternatively, we could just open a new question (or use this one) to name some users that we would like to see as candidates. Maybe this will encourage them to consider it.